# Run app from .bat file with administrator rights from startup?

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, startup, administrator

I am trying to use a batch file to run a list of programs from startup.  Windows automatically logs into a standard account.  How can I run the .bat at startup with admin rights, without prompting for a password every time?

.bat in startup folder:

```
@echo off
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\program.exe
cd C:\C:\Program Files (x86)\program.exe
cd C:\Users\M\desktop\folder\

TIMEOUT 60
startscript.py

exit
```

I found this command:

```
runas.exe /savecred /user:administrator "defrag c:"
```

but cannot get it working.

Thank you!

Comment: When using the second command, I continually receive errors stating the path is wrong, although it is definitely correct.  I am trying to make a first batch file that points to the second.

Comment: I can now run the python script sucessfully, but continue getting the directory is invalid for the first two programs.

Comment: Are you trying to `c`hange `d`irectory to two `.exe` files?  And I assume the `C:\C:\ ` is only a typo here, not in your actual script.  Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is a typo. It would just refuse to launch the program, msi afterburner without prompting for admin pass.